Multiclass UNet with n-dimensional satellite images
I'm trying to use a UNet in Pytorch to extract prediction masks from multidimensional (8 band) satellite images. I'm having trouble getting the prediction masks to look somewhat expected/coherent. I'm not sure if the issue is the way my training data is formatted, my training code, or the code I'm using to make predictions. My suspicion is that it is the way my training data is being fed to the model. I have 8 band satellite images and single band masks with values ranging 0-n number of classes with 0 being background and 1-n being target labels like this:

With the image shape being (8, 512, 512) and the mask shape being (512, 512) in the case of the single channel example, (512, 512, 8) in the OHE case, and (512, 512, 3) in the stacked case.
Some masks may contain all class labels, some may only have a couple or be background labels only. I've tried using these single channel masks, I've also converted them into 3 channel masks with the first channel being all the labels for a given image, and I've also tried one hot encoding them such that each mask is 0-n dimensions and each channel a different label with binary 0-1 for background/target.
EDIT
After changing the softmax dim=2, the outputs started looking a little better. However, it appears the model is not learning at all after the first few warmup epochs as the training loss decreases initially but then immediately plateaus or increases and the prediction masks stop making sense (either all black or random blobs). I suspect there is an issue with my training pipeline (below) or possibly due to the class imbalance with class 0 (background).
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import segmentation_models_pytorch as smp

image_dir = r'test_segmentation\images'
mask_dir = r'test_segmentation\masks'

data_dir=r'unet_training'
os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)

model_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'models')
os.makedirs(model_dir, exist_ok=True)

pred_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'predictions')
os.makedirs(pred_dir, exist_ok=True)

num_bands = 8
num_classes = 9
epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.001
weight_decay = 0
encoder = 'resnet50'
encoder_weights = 'imagenet'

model = smp.Unet(in_channels=num_bands, encoder_name=encoder, encoder_weights=encoder_weights, classes=num_classes).to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay)
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() if num_classes > 1 else nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    train_loss = 0
    val_loss = 0 

    train_loop = tqdm(enumerate(train_loader), total=len(train_loader), desc=f"Epoch {epoch} Training")
    
    model.train()
    
    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in train_loop:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        data = data.float().to(device)
        targets = targets.long().to(device)
        predictions = model(data)
        loss = loss_function(predictions, targets)
        
        train_loss += loss.item()

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        train_loop.set_postfix(loss=train_loss)

    val_loop = tqdm(enumerate(val_loader), total=len(val_loader), desc=f"Epoch {epoch} Validation")

    model.eval()
    
    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in val_loop:
        data, targets = data.to(device).float(), targets.to(device).long()
        preds = model(data)

        val_loss = loss_function(preds, targets).item()

        softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=2)
        preds = torch.argmax(softmax(preds), dim=1).cpu().numpy()
        preds = np.array(preds[0, :, :], dtype=np.uint8)
        labels = np.array(targets.cpu().numpy()[0, :, :], dtype=np.uint8)

        #save prediction and label mask
        pred_path = os.path.join(pred_dir, f"{epoch}_{batch_idx}_pred.png")
        label_path = os.path.join(pred_dir, f"{epoch}_{batch_idx}_label.png")
        io.imsave(pred_path, preds)
        io.imsave(label_path, labels)

        val_loop.set_postfix(loss=val_loss)
    
    avg_train_loss = train_loss / (batch_idx + 1)
    avg_val_loss = val_loss/ (batch_idx + 1)

    print(f"\nEpoch {epoch} Train Loss: {avg_train_loss}, Val Loss: {avg_val_loss}")

    checkpoint_name = os.path.join(model_dir, f"{modeltype}_bands{num_bands}_classes{num_classes}_{encoder}_{learning_rate}_{epoch}.pt")
    
    if epoch == 1:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), checkpoint_name)
    elif epoch % 10 == 0:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), checkpoint_name)
    elif epoch == epochs:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), checkpoint_name)
    else:
        pass


Your target mask should be a (512, 512) image (ie no channels) of just integer values - this is the format expected by cross entropy loss. Also make sure you are applying softmax on the correct dimension. It looks like you are using dim=1, but if your output is (512, 512, n_classes) it should be dim=2. Remove images with only background from the training dataset, they will degrade the model. The overall system you build should have a binary classification model to filter out background-only images before sending them to the segmentation model

Thanks for your insight. I changed the dim to 2 and the output was different but still doesn't seem correct. Something still seems off but maybe the model still needs to train longer, I'm not sure. Regarding input/output shapes, my input image is (512, 512, 8), the tensor of that image is ([8, 512, 512]) , the output from the model is ([1, 8, 512, 512]) and ([8, 512, 512]) when I squeeze it along 0. After applying softmax its ([1, 8, 512, 512]) and then (1, 512, 512) when I apply argmax

Does the train loss go down at all? Useful to print at each epoch. Try fitting just a single image or one small batch - keep running it until the loss goes down further and further. A sensible output should start emerging, like blobs roughly in the right place. If not, it suggests the pipeline is broken somewhere since it's failing to learn at all. Might also be worth working with down-sampled images initially and limiting the mask to a single channel. They will help the net converge more quickly and highlight convergence issues.

Thanks @MuhammedYunus. It appears something may be broken in my train/validation pipeline as the loss goes down initially and has some relatively normal looking outputs but then after a few warmup epochs loss stops decreasing and outputs are all black. I can update my question with new example outputs and my training code.

Hi. CrossEntropy loss expect the label tensor to contain integers corresponding to each classes, so the tensor label remains (512,512) and contains integers between 0 and N-1 where N is number of classes.

Change to softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1) in order to softmax over the channels dimension dim=1
In the training loop that starts for batch_idx, (data, targets) in train_loop:, check the following:

targets.shape should be (batch, 512, 512)

At each pixel, targets should be an integer ranging [0, n_classes - 1], denoting the class


data.shape should be (batch, channels, 512, 512)
model(data).shape should be (batch, channels, 512, 512)


Original reply:
Does the train loss go down at all? Useful to print it out at each epoch.
Try fitting just a single image or one small batch - keep running it until the loss goes down further and further. A sensible output should start emerging, like blobs roughly in the right place. If not, it suggests the pipeline is broken somewhere since it's failing to learn at all
It might also be worth working with down-sampled images initially and limiting the mask to a single channel. They will help the net converge more quickly and highlight convergence issues.

Thanks. Just to confirm, I should be applying softmax to the predictions during training? Does that get need to be applied before or after sending the predictions and targets to the loss function? I think my shapes are looking right, I changed my training data to reduce the image size and reduce the number of class 0 pixels: Data Shape: torch.Size([1, 8, 128, 128]), Target Shape: torch.Size([1, 128, 128]), Prediction Shape: torch.Size([1, 5, 128, 128]), Softmax Shape: torch.Size([1, 5, 128, 128])

I was unclear on that, sorry. I've corrected the post. I meant to refer to the softmax in the val loop (it's not used in training) - it should be dim=1. The dimensions are looking correct, as you've said. What if you make the mask simpler - just a binary mask where 1=all the non-background, and 0=background. Is there any semblance of a segmentation at the output.

Thanks! I think I've got it solved now. In addition to the softmax, I was noticing it was taking way too long for train loss to decrease. After 250 epochs, nothing great was happening but I saw one of the outputs looked decent but was transposed from the target mask. It looks like my input images were getting transposed and changing that seems to have helped massively. Still work to be done I think but I think the major issue has been resolved.
